# How to turn off "REAL" PCIe power for a GPU device on Linux

Tags: linux, gpu, gpgpu, pci, pci-e

I want to turn off "REAL" PCIe power for a GPU device on Linux.
I found some home pages, but they could not cut the "REAL" power.

I monitored the AC power usage, but all of them could not cut the real power usage. Could you tell me how to turn off PCI power for a device?

The followings are the methods I tired.

Method.1

```
Turn off
# echo "0" > /sys/bus/pci/slots/"SLOT No."/power
turn on
# echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/slots/"SLOT No."/power
```

Method.2

```
Unbind. 0000:0c:00.0 is device ID.
# echo -n "0000:0c:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/"DEVICE NAME"/unbind 
Bind.
# echo -n "0000:0c:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/"DEVICE NAME"/bind
```

Method.3

```
Remove. 0000:0c:00.0 is device ID.
# echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:0c\:00.0/remove 
Recover.
# echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

I confirm that ASPM (Active State Power Management) is supported on the BIOS and effective on Linux. The Linux is booted with "pcie_aspm=force" kernel option.

Comment: This question is related to PCIe. Can you please add pci-e tag to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The hardware to do that doesn't exist -- on all normal PC hardware, PCIe slots receive power whenever the computer is running.

Cutting off power to individual PCIe slots would require a significant amount of additional power management hardware on PC motherboards. None of this hardware would ever be used in normal operation, so there would be no benefit to the added cost (and hardware complexity) of such a design.

Comment: Can I cut all PCIe power?
Linux's suspend mechanism cuts all power except memory and goes to CPU sleep mode (S3).

Comment: No. S3 sleep comes as a bundle deal. You can't selectively cut power to PCIe devices -- the hardware has no way of doing this.

Comment: I am confused with PCI Bus and PCI Device. A PCI device is a state machine which can control the power state from L0 (Full Active Link) to L1 (Low Power Standby) and L2 (Low Power Sleep). This figure shows the transition [link](http://news.mynavi.jp/photo/column/sopinion/111/images/zu2l.gif) .I want to control the power state transition.  I also fond an interesting news "Power-Saving PCI Express L1 PM Substate Support Coming To Linux 4.11"  [link](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ASPM-PCIE-L1-PM-Sub) I want to control the power transition.